# Location and Size are not responding on an OxyPlot Object in C#

Tags: c#, plot, controls, oxyplot

I seem to have an issue fixing the location and size of the Plot. is this normal or al i missing something?

My code goes like this:

```
GPlot.Model = new PlotModel();
GPlot.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
GPlot.Enabled = true;
GPlot.Parent = Top_Tabs.TabPages[2]; // Putting it on a Tab

// At this point the Location And Size of GPlot, are those of the containing parent

GPlot.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(279, 224);
GPlot.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(10, 10);

// Last Two lines had no effect.

this.Matlab.Controls.Add(GPlot);
```

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove this line:

```
GPlot.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
```

`DockStyle.Fill` means: Set the control's size and location to fit exactly into it's parent's ClientRectangle. It will ignore the location and size you set manually.